# Unable to lower brightness in lenovo legion y530

Tags: 16.04, brightness, xbacklight

I have tried various methods  found on the internet, including xbacklight .
The main issue is I have no folder inside /sys/class/backlight.

Usually others happnened to have a folder like intel_backlight and inside it they had other files which they could change to change to backlight.

But I dont have any folder in it.

[My details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDINv.png)

It may have something to do with the graphic drivers as the sometimes screen tearing happens when watching youtube videos as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to change kernel parameters.

The only thing left after "quiet splash" was "i915.alpha_support=1"

I removed the following parameters after changing the kernel version to 4.18.5 :

"nomodeset"
"$vt_handoff"
"acpi_backlight=off"
"acpi_backlight=vendor"

So only remaining parameters was  "i915.alpha_support=1"

By doing this , it also removed lag after login screen.

I think "nomodeset" was responsible for that.